# In App Purchase for multiple accounts subscriptions

Tags: ios, ipad, in-app-purchase

We are building a solution with a cloud Backend and an iPad application connecting to that Backend, strangely Apple rejected the application because the payement had to be done from the web and they are suggesting using In App-Purchase, my question here is :
Can the admin (the manager in our case) purchase multiple subscriptions to each of its employees to be used in separate devices from within the application, and is that OK with Apple IAP guidelines.
(We investigated the guidelines but we think a similar situation is not listed).

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Did you determine a solution ? I have same issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In App Purchases are active on the *account*, not the *device*.  This means that if someone purchases a subscription with a particular Apple ID any other device that is using that Apple ID can (must) access that subscription as well.  So if all the devices in your scenario use the same Apple ID then the manager purchases it once and then the other devices can use the 'restore' function to load the subscription onto those devices as well.

If each device has a different Apple ID associated with it then the subscription will be charged to each individual person's Apple ID.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, we are aware that purchase is related to the Apple ID, we are asking about the case when each iPad uses a different Apple ID, in that case is it possible that the manager buy a pack of 10 subscriptions for example and then in our Backend define the userName/password/UDID for each one of the purchased accounts.

Comment: Remember that UDID is no longer available to you.  You can at best use username/password to limit access.  You COULD let the manager buy the passes (one-time user generated codes) and hand them out to people to assign to their device (managed completely on your end via username/password).